Quantitative definition of information without set cardinality or probability?
Suppose I know that some number x is an arbitrary natural number. Then I am told the piece of information that x is even. Philosophically, I have gained some information about x—I have knowledge about x that I did not have before; I have ruled out an infinite number of states that I a priori believed could be true about x. In fact, since I have ruled out exactly half of the possible natural numbers, I would intuitively believe that I have gained 1 bit of information.
However, under the standard mathematical definitions of information, this is not well-defined. Shannon information depends on the probability that x takes on particular values, and a uniform probability distribution is not defined over the natural numbers. Similarly, the set of all natural numbers and the set of all even natural numbers are both countably infinite, so I can't simply divide the number of elements in E by the number of elements in N.
It seems, definitively, that I have gained some information about x, and it seems like such a well-behaved case that there should be a way to quantify how much information (less than knowing that x is divisible by 4, more than knowing x is divisible by 1). Are there any theoretical and/or mathematical frameworks for defining this?

You can apply a convergent normalized exponential distribution for natural numbers for their prior uncertainties to be applicable for Shannon information. OTOH intuitively you’re describing them differently so algorithmic information theory with Kolmogorov complexity could be your fit though it’s incomputable due to the halting problem…

@DoubleKnot yeah, the issue is that the exponential distribution assumes I have an a priori reason to believe that x is more likely to be 1 than 64 or 20,000 or 194,512, which I do not have to begin with. I'm curious how Kolmogorov complexity would apply here—would it really take fewer bits to represent x only given that it is even?

A uniform probability distribution is defined over the natural numbers, the corresponding probability measure is called natural density. However, it is only finitely rather than countably additive, so you have to be careful with it because some standard results for countably additive measures do not apply. For example, the natural density of any individual number is 0, but the natural density of N is 1. It is 1/2 for even numbers, as expected.

Solomonoff probably would argue small numbers as stepping stones for defining larger ones, their universal priors ought to be larger. Apparently you need more to describe evens based on successor function, but not much, so there’s not much gain for your example since they are both infinite with same cardinality though it may feel a lot…

"In fact, since I have ruled out exactly half of the possible natural numbers, I would intuitively believe that I have gained 1 bit of information." -- I tell you that x is five.  How many bits of information have I given you?  The first bit is one, the second is zero, the third is one, the fourth is zero, the fifth is zero, the sixth is zero, the seventh is zero, the eighth is zero, the ninth is zero, the tenth is zero, the eleventh is zero, the twefth is zero, the thirteenth is zero, the fourteenth is zero, the fifteenth is zero, the sixteenth is zero, the seventeenth is zero, the eightee...

@Conifold -- very cool link to "natural density" - makes sense and would be a good topic in an advanced undergrad probability course to help stretch thinking :)

@Him I think that conflates the bits required to encode "x = 5" with the bits of information gained. "x = 9910" requires more bits to encode using a standard base-2 encoding than "x = 5", but I don't see why "x = 9910" conveys more information than "x = 5". They both rule the state space down from an infinite number of possibilities to a single possibility.

@Lysanderoth "I don't see why "x = 9910" conveys more information than "x = 5". They both rule the state space down from an infinite number of possibilities to a single possibility." EXACTLY!  If every natural number was equally likely to have been chosen, then "x=9910" conveys an infinite amount of information.

@Him true, but a philosophical bullet I'm willing to bite when talking about an infinite set.

You know that the number x in question is a natural number. Considered in the dual system x is represented as a finite sequence of digits 0 and 1.

If you are told the first digit you got 1 bit of information, if you
are told in addition the second digit you have in sum 2 bit, etc.
After a finite number n of steps the procedure terminates, and you
got n bit of information.
Of course you do not know a priori the number n of necessary steps,
i.e. the number n of bits.

The procedure is similar if you take into account for each step the
additional information whether the current digit is the final digit.


The idea is to split the search in a finite sequence of binary alternatives.
